# Sidebar with Groups driven by Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I've searched everywhere for a sidebar example / tutorial that uses Core Data.  The only one I've found is this tutorial by Mikael Hallendal:

http://simplyhacking.com/source-list-with-core-data.html

I'll be honest, I'm new to programming and had trouble getting it to work.  Normally, given enough time, I can figure something out for myself.  I've been at this for over a week though with no such luck.

What I am after is a sidebar with three group items:

- A static group at the top with one child item.
- A second group called Favourites that will display all contents of my entity that have a "Favourites" boolean set to YES.
- And a third group called History that will display the remaining contents of my entity.

The best example I have found is Apple's SidebarDemo:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

I tinkered with the sample code and managed to replace their static arrays with a fetched array, but of course it doesn't react with the core data at all.  It simply displays the array.

If anyone can help me out with this I will be eternally grateful.